# Unusual peaks of 100% CPU usage in amazon EC2 instance

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpu-usage

I have very unusual peaks at my Amazon EC2 CPU usage and network in/out simultaneously.

This is the CPU usage:
[image: CPU usage]

THis is the Network in:
[image: Network in]

And my network out:
[image: Network out]

How can I know what process, file or command is doing this?

How can I recognize the problem and solve it?

Answer (score 3):

This is something that I would use `top`/`htop` for and/or `ps aux` for.  However, with your issue, you will likely have to be watching the server at the times in which these spike occur so `top` or `htop` are probably better options.  I would likely think that there is a cron that would be causing this as it appears that you have something occurring every hour. so take a look in /etc/cron.hourly as once you see the spike see if it references anything from that directory.

References:

https://superuser.com/questions/117913/ps-aux-output-meaning

http://linux.die.net/man/1/top

http://linux.die.net/man/1/ps

http://linux.die.net/man/1/htop